# Retrieve the First digit of an extremely large number

Tags: java, biginteger, digit

There is an array of int type. I have to multiply some of its elements and report the product%(10^9 + 7) and the first digit of product. 
I've tried this using the BigInteger class of Java but the answer reported isn't correct.
I just want to know if any such algorithm exists to keep track of the first digit and which doesn't use BigInteger.

This is what I had tried doing.

```
c= (Prod.bitCount())*Math.log10(2);
c2= (int)c;
First= (Prod.divide(TEN.pow(c2))).intValue(); 
if(First/10 != 0) First/=10;
System.out.print(First+" ");
//finding Prod%M
System.out.print(Prod.mod(M)+"\n");
```

Comment: can you please add sample data and expected result, the code you tried using `BigInteger` **and** *incorrect answer reported*. Thanks! ;)

Comment: `BigInteger` can be converted into a String representation and you can use `string.charAt(0)` to get the first number

Comment: Here's the question:https://www.codechef.com/JUNE16/problems/FRJUMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int x = Integer.parseInt(""+prod.toString().charAt(0));`

I think somebody had a similar comment above.

Comment: I've tried doing this, but still I get Wrong answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? What answer are you getting, and what value are you using?

Comment: Ive given my code above. Im getting the correct output for the sample IO, but for the actual input data, the Online Judge says that my answer is Wrong. I've given the link of the question in the comments

Comment: What's wrong about your answer, the first digit part or the modulo part?

Answer (score 0):

```
 int prod;
     ...
 int first = prod / 
    ((int)Math.pow(10, (int)Math.log10(prod)));
```

This is untested, just off the top of my head, but should give the general idea.

Comment: prod is extremely big, so data overflow occurs and hence wrong result.

Comment: You asked if it could be done without a`BigInteger`; I gave an answer that doesn't use `BigInteger`.  If you're saying `Prod` **has** to be a `BigInteger`, then @TheLostMind has the right idea.

Comment: What I need is the first digit and the modulo value, so I should be able to work out without using BigInteger because poeple have submitted the code in other languages which dont support BigInteger like classes